# How to add owl carousel slider for recent view products in Magento 2.2.2 version with knockout js?

Tags: magento2.2.2

How to adding owl carousel slider for recent view products. I have successfully added it for related product, up-sell products etc. But I am not able to add it for recent view because in Magento 2.2.2 its is rendered through knockout js and UI component.

Comment: Did you ever managed to get this working? I am doing the exact same thing right now, and can not use owl-carousel the way I used it on all of the other product listings, because of the way the recently viewed products are rendered! Thank you in advance, if you're reading this!